# Iterate over list in Python using for loop

Tags: python

Below is my script in main.py which I was hoping would return "true", but doesn't seem to register anything:

**main.py**

```
import config

business_number = int(678)
    
for company in config.companies:
    if int(company.business_id) == business_number:
        print("True")
```

**config.py:**

```
companies: [Company] = [
            Company("ABC", "345", 3.00, 10.00, 200.00),
            Company("DEF", "678", 5.00, 10.00, 500.00)
]
```

**company .py**

```
class Company:
    name = None
    business_id = None
    max_share_price = None
    min_total = None
    max_total = None
    
    def __init__(self, name, business_id, max_share_price, min_total, max_total):
        self.name = name
        self.business_id = business_id
        self.max_share_price = max_share_price
        self.min_total = min_total
        self.max_total = max_total
```

Comment: There are a weird things in this code (invalid type annotation, needless `int` conversion), but it *runs* fine for me (once I add `from company import Company` to `config.py` that is) -- `python main.py` -> `True` printed to stdout.

Comment: Where is the Company class defined?

Comment: How is this question related to Selenium or ChromeDriver? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

To get your correct answer put the following line on the top of the `config.py`:

```py
from company import Company
```

Then run `main.py` again to see your desired answer.